# Showing an $L^2$ convergence (with convergence rate)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

We have $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb Z}$ iid random variables with $1\le X_i \le2$ almost surely.

We define $X(x,\omega) \equiv X_i (\omega)$ if $x\in [i,i+1[$ (so it is bounded almost surely) and, for $\epsilon >0$, $X_\epsilon (x, \omega) \equiv X(x/\epsilon, \omega)$.

Define for $x\in [0,1]$

$$u_\epsilon(x,\omega)= \int_0^x \frac {c_\epsilon(\omega) - F(x)}{X_\epsilon(x,\omega)}\, dx$$

where $F$ is an $L^1(]0,1[)$ function (we can add continuity of $F$ on $[0,1]$ if it helps solving the problem) and $c_\epsilon(\omega)$ is defined by

$$c_\epsilon(\omega)\equiv \frac{\int_0^1 \frac{F(y)}{X_\epsilon(y,\omega)} \, dy}{\int_0^1\frac 1 {X_\epsilon(y,\omega)}\, dy}$$

It can be shown that for each $x\in [0,1]$, we have almost surely (we use law of large numbers and the density of the staircase functions in the $L^1$ functions)

$$u_\epsilon(x,\omega) \to u_0(x) \equiv -E[\frac 1 {X_1}](\int_0^x F(y) dy - x \int_0^1 F(y) dy) $$ when $\epsilon \to 0^+$

We would like to find a function $f$ such that

$$\Vert u_\epsilon - u_0\Vert_{L^2(]0,1[ \times \Omega)} \le f(\epsilon) \to 0$$

when $\epsilon \to 0^+$

Related questions:

[Show that those random quantities converge in distribution to a normal variable (hard analysis problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814040/show-that-those-random-quantities-converge-in-distribution-to-a-normal-variable/2816197?noredirect=1#comment5809111_2816197)

[How to use the Lindeberg CLT in this scenario ? (analysis problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2817622/how-to-use-the-lindeberg-clt-in-this-scenario-analysis-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Controlling this function in $L^2$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2817241/controlling-this-function-in-l2-norm?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: And what prevents you from honestly estimating the variance of  $u_\varepsilon(x)$ for fixed $x$?

Comment: Could you write what you have in mind ? I don't see your point.

Comment: I will later, but the function $f$ will depend on $F$ and can tend to $0$ as slowly as one wants if $F$ is bad enough. Is it OK for your purposes?

Comment: Yes this is fine, and you can even suppose that $F$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ if it helps.

Comment: ]0,1[ is the open interval that goes from 0 to 1, sometimes written (0,1).

Comment: @fedja the bounty is ending tomorrow in case you're interested in gaining more rep. I won't put another bounty unfortunately.