# Controlling this function in $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

We have $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb Z}$ iid random variables with $1\le X_i \le2$ almost surely.

We define $X(x,\omega) \equiv X_i (\omega)$ if $x\in [i,i+1[$ (so it is bounded almost surely) and, for $\epsilon >0$, $X_\epsilon (x, \omega) \equiv X(x/\epsilon, \omega)$.

Define for $x\in [0,1]$

$$err_\epsilon(x,\omega)=\frac {\int_0^1 \frac {F(y)}{X_\epsilon(y,\omega)} dy}{X_\epsilon(x,\omega)\int_0^1 \frac {1}{X_\epsilon(y,\omega)} dy}$$

where $F$ is an $L^1(]0,1[)$ function (we can add continuity if it helps).

We would like to find functions $g$ and $f$ such that

$$\Vert err_\epsilon - g\Vert_{L^2(]0,1[ \times \Omega)} \le f(\epsilon) \to 0$$

when $\epsilon \to 0^+$

Related question: [How to use the Lindeberg CLT in this scenario ? (analysis problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2817622/how-to-use-the-lindeberg-clt-in-this-scenario-analysis-problem)